# Adding leading zeros back to ID variable

Tags: r

I am using the following ID data, I am trying to put the data back into the correct form.

The first 20 observations of the "incorrect ID" look like:

```
 [1] 11820096867 11820053047 13410057602 13410015341 14257205715 28382012393 13410001306 11820000771 11820000784 11820000884 11820011030
[12] 15230002545 13410015602 17336011108 11820000769 11820096867 11820053030 13410050602 11820053030 14257205715
```

This data can be split up into 4 sections `S`, `G`, `V` and `I`

I want to add back these leading zeros and separate the data into 4 columns.

```
S = 2 digits long
G = 1 digit long
V = 5 digits
I = 5 digits
```

I have been working backwards with these "incorrect ID´s" so for example the observation `11820000771` would be split into the last 5 digits (minus the leading zero) and would be = `I` the next 5 digits (minus the leading zero)  would be = V etc. So;

Example 1:

`11820000771` would be:

```
I = 0771
V = 82000
G = 1
S = 1
```

Example 2:

`14257205715` would be:

```
I = 5715
V = 25720
G = 4
S = 1
```

Example 3:

`13410015602` would be:

```
I = 15602
V = 4100
G = 3
S = 1
```

Example 4:

`10943900008` would be:

```
I = 0008
V = 94390
G = 0
S = 1
```

In the documentation it states that the `leading zeros are not shown` for the "incorrect ID" data and have been removed.

In a second "correct" data frame this is what the `S`, `G`, `V` and `I` look like:

```
        S G     V     I
 [91,]  0 1 18200 97341
 [92,]  0 1 71990 15340
 [93,]  0 1 18200 87418
 [94,]  6 1 18200 38602
 [95,] 27 1 34100  1640
 [96,]  0 1 19699 30069
 [97,]  0 2 84694 59574
 [98,]  0 1 71990  1640
 [99,]  0 1 18200   771
[100,]  0 1 18200  1640
```

So

The first objective is to split the "incorrect ID´s" into the correct `S`, `G`, `V` and `I` similar to the above.

The second objective is to create a new ID key which looks like the following:

```
 [1] "00-01-73360-50661" "00-01-87692-30040" "00-01-34100-57509" "00-01-18200-53047" "00-03-70310-30703" "00-01-82000-72385"
 [7] "00-01-68213-09410" "00-01-18200-00771" "00-01-34100-50340" "00-03-73360-97341"
```

Where the `S`, `G`, `V` and `I` are combined and split by a `-` and leading zeros are added back to the data.

Overview:

I am trying to add back leading zeros to segments of an ID variable which is split into 4 maximum length sections. If a segment begins on a `0` then it is removed. If it begins on a number greater than `0` then no leading zero is added to the ID.

Hopefull I am clear, if I am not in any part let me know and I will clarify

DATA:

```
 ID <- c(11820096867, 11820053047, 13410057602, 13410015341, 14257205715, 
    28382012393, 13410001306, 11820000771, 11820000784, 11820000884, 
    11820011030, 15230002545, 13410015602, 17336011108, 11820000769, 
    11820096867, 11820053030, 13410050602, 11820053030, 14257205715, 
    11820011168, 27336097343, 13410015509, 12556924173, 13410001222, 
    18769227102, 18769210012, 13410048574, 13410057602, 28066095605, 
    17199030030, 11820011047, 13410057509, 13410017256, 13410050306, 
    18200072518, 13410001306, 11820053168, 11820053168, 11820096867, 
    11820043047, 18200072385, 11820043218, 13410029602, 13410030341, 
    17199030030, 17199000048, 18066095615, 15230002540, 13410015341, 
    17199030030, 13410057306, 11820011168, 13410059505, 17336011214, 
    11820096867, 11820000884, 13410003602, 31820000042, 13410015341, 
    11820000891, 13410000355, 11820096867, 13410031306, 17289010016, 
    11820053218, 11820053030, 11820000016, 11820011030, 17336011214, 
    13410015340, 2710000106005, 11820061030, 17089701331, 23410017306, 
    11820000016, 27199077005, 13410003256, 13410057341, 17199030030, 
    15230000435, 11820053218, 13410015341, 18769241103, 15230000434, 
    11820043218, 11820000842, 13410057340, 11820011047, 13410001340, 
    33410000354, 12210000170, 11820041218, 27336097343, 13410046874, 
    13410015340, 31820000697, 13410015306, 13410000007, 613598510062, 
    15230000022, 618516510505, 11820053218, 13410001602, 15146051460, 
    15230000022, 17031000024, 11820000884, 14182700012, 11820000784, 
    2710000106005, 18769233103, 17199010074, 17199030030, 18200072385, 
    11820011168, 11820000769, 16821309117, 11820053168, 13410050505, 
    11820043218, 11820053030, 13410017509, 17231163001, 15230002540, 
    33410000354, 18769210014, 15230002545, 27031030701, 15230000002, 
    18769240020, 12210000170, 23410017306, 13410050340, 17199000048, 
    15230000434, 11820096867, 15230002903, 13410057340, 28066095605, 
    11820079047, 17199000048, 11820011030, 17199000048, 27336097343, 
    13410057341, 13410000555, 13410050574, 18769230050, 11820096867, 
    11820000884, 18769210014, 21820086167, 11820053168, 11820041218, 
    13410015306, 715643501208, 11820002990, 613598512001, 16821309117, 
    13410000355, 33410000354, 13410057602, 11820000126, 17089701331, 
    11820027168, 17336035201, 27336097343, 13410057340, 11820000769, 
    11820053218, 11820011168, 16206705142, 11820000884, 11820053168, 
    11820011168, 18066095615, 15230000017, 11820003982, 11820043218, 
    17199030030, 11820000466, 27336097343, 11820096867, 11820011030, 
    15230002966, 611969902000, 11820011030, 17289010011, 711820053025, 
    23410017306, 11820096867, 12210000170, 13410057341, 18382072553, 
    15230000434, 13410057306, 13410048574, 12556971416, 618516510505, 
    13410014574, 13410017340, 27336082341, 13410001306, 18200072385, 
    13410015341, 11820079047, 15230000435, 17336035201, 13410015341, 
    13410051574, 17289010011, 11820096867, 13410050574, 13410001306, 
    15230000434, 21820000801, 13410001602, 17089701331, 23410017306, 
    13410050306, 11820053030, 11820000771, 11820000016, 11820000884, 
    18200072385, 15230002903, 17143945712, 11820004989, 16206705155, 
    11820011030, 13410050602, 16821309117, 18769233103, 11820011030, 
    13410003602, 17199030069, 23410017306, 17336013661, 15230002540, 
    13410050340, 15230002903, 18769283102, 13410057602, 17336011108, 
    27336097343, 17199070002, 13410057306, 15230000966, 13410072805, 
    11820000693, 17336035301, 21820000115, 15230000536, 31820000042, 
    13410057340, 17143932012, 11820053047, 13410017256, 13410001222, 
    18769241103, 17199030030, 13410015340, 10948700007, 11820086031, 
    11820043218, 13410031306, 13410057602, 17199030030, 11820003982, 
    11820011168, 17336011214, 16206705155, 11820053030, 13410057340, 
    15230002545, 613598510062, 13410057340, 2710000106005, 13410057306, 
    11820004990, 18200072518, 17336013343, 18066095615, 11820053218, 
    13410048574, 13410015306, 11820096867, 13410015340, 18469400001, 
    13410048574, 11820053218, 13410001340, 11820053168, 18769233103, 
    13410050306, 13410010602, 15230002545, 18066095615, 11820000106, 
    11820002992, 11820000693, 17199000048, 13410057306, 11820000771, 
    13410015341, 17031000009, 13410078574, 27336097343, 21820000647, 
    13410015341, 13410057256, 31820000697, 15230000017, 13410030341, 
    13410000175, 16821309117, 11820000771, 21820086167, 613598510062, 
    13410048505, 13410001306, 13410007306, 13410001505, 11820079047, 
    18806705542, 37336097341, 12210007500, 13410072805, 18066095615, 
    11820011047, 13410078574, 31820000697, 18417341130, 16206705155, 
    11820053168, 13410015341, 13410057306, 13410017256, 18382023473, 
    15230000435, 613598512001, 14182700712, 13410057340, 13410057509, 
    11820053168, 11820011218, 15230000434, 15230002966, 13410001602, 
    17199000027, 13410057306, 13410050340, 13410057341, 15230000434, 
    13410057602, 11820053047, 15146051460, 27199077008, 13410057340, 
    13410001306, 23410000005, 11820053218, 11820003982, 23410068505, 
    11820000833, 17031037037, 11820000466, 16206705155, 11820043218, 
    11820011030, 27336082341, 11820003982, 23410017306, 11820043218, 
    17336013302, 13410057341, 17336035201, 17199030005, 11820000884, 
    18200072385, 13410017505, 11820096418, 15230000540, 11820015168, 
    715643501201, 16821302112, 613598512001, 11820053168, 11820053047, 
    13410010505, 13410000554, 21820086167, 15230000416, 13410001340, 
    11820053030, 13410001340, 11820096867, 23410003505, 11820053218, 
    23410000005, 18200072385, 15230002545, 23410000005, 11820096867, 
    11820001991, 21820086167, 13410001602, 13410015341, 13410057602, 
    13410000355, 13410007306, 13410057602, 18066095615, 18382012368, 
    12210001640, 15230000434, 13410057340, 13410015256, 28382012393, 
    13410050306, 11820053047, 11820000891, 13410000559, 11820000466, 
    18015761194, 11820096418, 11820000891, 11820096418, 17199030030, 
    13410057509, 18769241103, 11820096867, 16821309117, 16821309117, 
    11820079047, 27336097343, 2710000106744, 11820000784, 11820000884, 
    18066095675, 11820096418, 13410015341, 11820053168, 11820053168, 
    11820096867, 11820004990, 613598510062, 15230000434, 2710000106005, 
    15230000434, 11820053047, 613598512001, 31820000042, 11820096379, 
    15230000435, 11820011030, 11820053030, 12210001640, 13410003306, 
    18200072385, 18417340130, 11820053168, 13410072805, 11820053218, 
    11820015168, 13410001509, 13410031306, 17089701325, 17199048004, 
    11820096867, 13410001509, 18549811113, 18066095937, 17336011341, 
    11820011025, 11820011030, 11820096418, 18066095935, 11820015168, 
    18200072385, 13410007341, 17336011348, 13410007306, 13410057602, 
    13410001341, 18769241102, 13410057340, 13410001602, 17199036400, 
    17289000016, 11820096867, 16821302117, 13410057306, 13410057306, 
    11820000833, 14182700712, 11820011030, 11820011030, 15230000440
    )
```

EDIT 2:

As was pointed out in the comments to remove the leading zeroes of the below data.

This data is the "correct" data in the correct format. What I am now trying to do is to just remove the leading zeros from each section in the below data. So taking `00-01-18200-00987` would be split into 4 columns as before and the leading zeros removed.

```
S = 0
G = 1
V = 18200
I = 0987
```

Data:

```
IDs <- c("00-01-41827-00712", "00-01-52300-01540", "00-01-18200-00987", 
"00-01-83820-07131", "00-01-34100-01222", "00-01-34100-50602", 
"00-01-52300-00536", "00-01-42572-05715", "00-01-34100-25574", 
"00-01-73360-73149", "00-01-34100-51574", "00-01-34100-07602", 
"00-01-89961-00420", "00-01-71990-90029", "00-01-34100-31341", 
"00-02-34100-30602", "00-01-34100-17536", "00-01-34100-57602", 
"00-01-18200-11047", "00-01-34100-00880", "00-01-34100-07602", 
"07-01-67084-27455", "00-01-34100-07340", "00-01-80660-95615", 
"00-01-34100-50222", "00-01-34100-15509", "00-01-72311-63009", 
"00-01-18200-54028", "06-01-19699-02000", "00-01-73360-35201", 
"06-01-85165-10504", "06-01-34986-10003", "00-03-70310-30703", 
"00-01-18200-53168", "00-01-18200-01991", "00-01-89961-10120", 
"00-01-82000-72385", "00-01-18200-00784", "00-01-71990-30030", 
"00-01-72890-00011", "00-01-34100-00622", "00-01-18200-15168", 
"00-01-52300-00440", "00-01-34100-00355", "00-01-71990-00048", 
"00-01-34100-77435", "00-01-80157-11125", "00-01-52300-01301", 
"06-01-85165-10505", "00-01-87692-83102", "00-01-34100-50505", 
"00-01-34100-00355", "00-01-52300-00440", "00-01-34100-50340", 
"00-01-73360-13343", "00-01-80660-95301", "00-01-34100-14505", 
"00-01-34100-59574", "00-01-34100-07306", "00-01-18200-53168", 
"00-01-34100-15256", "27-01-00001-06502", "00-01-71990-77828", 
"00-01-18200-43218", "00-01-73360-13343", "00-01-72311-63001", 
"00-01-18200-00987", "00-01-18200-79047", "00-01-18200-00466", 
"00-01-82000-72385", "00-01-34100-57602", "00-02-34100-25505", 
"00-01-34100-01341", "00-03-73360-97341", "00-01-18200-00987", 
"00-01-34100-00488", "00-01-18200-15168", "00-01-34100-01306", 
"00-02-18200-29031", "00-01-34100-48602", "00-01-85498-73837", 
"00-02-34100-62509", "00-01-34100-00009", "00-02-34100-17306", 
"00-01-18200-00106", "00-01-41827-00712", "00-01-71990-70002", 
"00-01-82488-12700", "00-01-72890-00030", "00-01-18200-00956", 
"00-01-84173-32130", "00-01-52300-00536", "00-01-80660-95625", 
"00-01-22100-00157", "00-01-34100-03306", "00-01-18200-00639", 
"00-01-18200-15047", "00-01-85498-73837", "00-01-22100-00170", 
"00-01-52300-02540", "00-01-52300-02540", "00-01-34100-68574", 
"00-01-34100-03509", "00-01-18200-00978", "00-01-71990-10006", 
"00-01-52300-02540", "00-01-18200-01991", "00-03-34100-00354", 
"00-01-18200-03982", "07-01-18200-53025", "00-01-18200-03982", 
"00-01-72890-00016", "00-01-34100-15509", "00-01-84173-10545", 
"00-01-34100-03340", "00-01-71990-48004", "00-01-34100-62340", 
"00-01-71990-77828", "00-01-34100-00904", "00-01-71990-00047", 
"00-01-87692-10012", "00-01-34100-07341", "00-01-18200-79047", 
"00-01-85725-00005", "00-01-52300-00540", "00-01-71990-30030", 
"00-01-34100-50574", "00-02-73360-82341", "00-01-34100-57306", 
"00-01-72311-63011", "00-01-73360-35201", "00-01-34100-50574", 
"00-01-71990-10033", "00-01-71990-00048", "00-01-34100-57536", 
"00-01-70897-01331", "00-01-52300-00434", "00-01-71990-48016", 
"00-01-34100-31602", "00-01-18200-00834", "00-01-34100-31306", 
"00-01-18200-11168", "00-01-34100-00252", "00-02-72890-00012", 
"00-01-52300-00022", "00-02-34100-17306", "00-01-52300-00017", 
"00-01-82488-12356", "00-01-18200-04989", "00-01-34100-01222", 
"00-03-34100-00354", "00-01-34100-14505", "00-01-18200-00933", 
"00-01-52300-00416", "00-02-18200-29031", "00-01-18200-00865", 
"00-01-82488-12910", "00-01-80660-95625", "00-01-41827-00076", 
"00-01-18200-27168", "00-01-34100-53505", "00-01-34100-01340", 
"00-01-18200-02989", "00-01-34100-62505", "00-01-73360-50202", 
"00-01-34100-01256", "00-01-71250-40205", "00-01-34100-15340", 
"00-02-18200-29031", "00-01-72311-63012", "00-03-18200-00697", 
"00-02-18200-00166", "00-01-34100-00491", "00-01-52300-02966", 
"00-01-22100-00171", "00-01-34100-14574", "00-01-49483-18000", 
"00-01-71990-09511", "00-01-34100-50222", "00-02-71250-00019", 
"00-01-34100-03509", "00-01-18200-53168", "00-01-34100-57306", 
"00-01-34100-17505", "00-02-34100-17306", "00-01-87000-50882", 
"00-01-34100-50574", "00-01-83820-12360", "00-01-34100-10505", 
"00-01-71990-70002", "00-03-70897-01123", "00-01-18200-00833", 
"00-01-34100-57256", "00-01-34100-62340", "07-01-19256-00058", 
"00-01-71250-40205", "00-01-09487-00007", "00-01-18200-00833", 
"00-01-83820-23473", "00-01-34100-00355", "00-01-34100-01256", 
"00-01-71439-34806", "00-01-34100-51306", "00-01-34100-50306", 
"06-01-33745-13000", "00-01-34100-00904", "00-01-18200-03982", 
"00-01-18200-00769", "00-01-52300-00966", "00-01-52300-00022", 
"00-01-52300-00540", "00-01-71990-10074", "00-02-18200-00801", 
"00-01-71990-30030", "00-01-18200-96867", "00-02-18200-87418", 
"00-01-34100-15222", "00-01-34100-15340", "00-01-87692-40020", 
"00-01-18200-00126", "00-01-71439-34806", "00-01-34100-15256", 
"00-02-18200-00701", "00-02-73360-82301", "00-01-68213-03112", 
"00-01-73360-80301", "00-01-34100-46805", "00-01-18200-11025", 
"00-01-34100-53505", "00-02-18200-00647", "00-01-18200-00974", 
"00-01-62067-05172", "00-01-71990-30069", "00-01-34100-01528", 
"00-02-83820-12393", "00-02-18200-87418", "00-01-34100-01509", 
"00-01-34100-57602", "00-01-34100-15509", "00-01-34100-03509", 
"00-01-34100-01602", "00-01-34100-50222", "00-01-34100-67505", 
"00-01-84173-37133", "00-02-34100-25505", "00-01-18200-00834", 
"00-01-71990-00028", "00-01-34100-03602", "00-01-22100-00171", 
"00-01-18200-00106", "00-01-83741-10012", "00-01-73360-11348", 
"00-01-80660-95935", "00-01-18200-86418", "00-01-22100-01640", 
"00-01-84173-32130", "00-01-71990-48016", "00-01-62067-05172", 
"00-01-18200-00891", "00-01-52300-00022", "00-01-34100-62340", 
"00-01-34100-50306", "00-01-34100-17256", "00-01-34100-57306", 
"00-01-62067-05172", "00-01-85725-11508", "00-03-18200-00697", 
"00-01-34100-01505", "00-01-18200-00466", "00-01-34100-00271", 
"00-01-18200-43218", "00-01-70897-01331", "00-01-18200-00974", 
"00-03-34100-00304", "00-02-34100-00005", "00-01-80157-11016", 
"00-01-34100-57256", "00-01-34100-17505", "06-01-13008-71310", 
"00-01-34100-57306", "00-01-34100-00559", "00-01-52300-02540", 
"00-01-82054-80441", "00-01-71990-10033", "00-02-73360-82341", 
"00-01-83820-12360", "00-02-18200-00166", "00-01-18200-00834", 
"00-01-62067-05172", "00-01-52300-02903", "00-02-34100-17306", 
"00-01-80660-95937", "00-01-52300-00536", "00-01-34100-77435", 
"00-01-70310-37037", "00-01-73360-35201", "00-01-34100-57306", 
"00-01-18200-61047", "00-01-62067-38072", "00-01-34100-50574", 
"07-01-19256-00054", "00-01-34100-62505", "00-02-83741-00006", 
"00-03-70897-01123", "00-01-34100-57341", "00-01-34100-25574", 
"00-01-34100-00554", "00-03-18200-00042", "06-01-35985-00016", 
"00-01-34100-15340", "00-01-18200-04990", "00-01-73360-50661", 
"00-01-52300-00022", "00-01-34100-50340", "00-02-18200-00801", 
"00-01-18200-00769", "00-03-34100-00354", "00-01-49483-11200", 
"00-01-73360-35301", "00-01-34100-50602", "07-02-39165-00125", 
"00-01-71990-10074", "00-01-70897-01331", "00-01-71439-22033", 
"00-02-82488-00006", "00-01-18200-00670", "06-01-35985-00016", 
"00-01-71990-48016", "00-01-22100-07500", "00-01-34100-17602", 
"00-01-73360-11214", "00-01-34100-10602", "00-01-18200-11168", 
"00-01-34100-31306", "00-01-18200-00468", "00-02-82488-00006", 
"00-01-87692-10012", "00-02-82488-00006", "00-01-18200-79047", 
"00-01-87692-30040", "00-01-34100-01509", "00-02-83741-00006", 
"27-01-00001-06505", "06-01-85165-10505", "00-01-18200-86418", 
"00-01-18200-53168", "00-01-34100-67602", "00-01-80660-95625", 
"00-01-71990-00048", "00-01-62067-05155", "00-01-71990-48004", 
"00-01-18200-61047", "00-01-18200-00313", "00-02-83820-12393", 
"00-01-71990-77828", "00-01-18200-00126", "00-01-71990-30030", 
"00-01-34100-01602", "00-01-82488-12345", "00-01-71670-04064", 
"00-01-34100-03306", "00-01-18200-00964", "00-01-34100-50505", 
"00-01-18200-00974", "06-01-85165-10707", "00-02-18200-29031", 
"00-01-68213-03112", "00-01-34100-10505", "00-01-18200-04989", 
"00-01-34100-17505", "00-01-72890-00020", "00-01-72311-63011", 
"00-01-34100-01222", "00-01-84173-32130", "07-01-60890-95602", 
"00-01-70897-18331", "00-01-72890-00020", "00-01-87692-27102", 
"06-01-35985-12001", "00-01-73360-35301", "00-01-70897-01331", 
"00-01-18200-04990", "00-01-18200-00769", "00-01-18200-04997", 
"00-01-70897-01125", "00-01-18200-41218", "00-01-18200-92867", 
"00-04-34100-00152", "00-01-18200-53218", "00-01-34100-10505", 
"00-01-84694-00001", "00-01-34100-62340", "00-01-52300-00435", 
"00-01-34100-25602", "00-01-34100-62340", "00-01-62067-05155", 
"00-01-34100-50505", "00-01-18200-79047", "00-01-34100-00555", 
"00-01-18200-00466", "07-01-18200-53025", "00-01-71990-00007", 
"00-01-34100-07341", "00-01-89961-00120", "06-01-19699-00006", 
"00-02-18200-86167", "00-01-71439-22033", "00-01-09487-00007", 
"00-01-72311-63009", "00-01-73360-11214", "00-01-42572-05715", 
"00-01-34100-50340", "00-01-34100-31341", "00-02-22100-02500", 
"00-02-80660-95785", "00-01-71990-70002", "07-01-98373-12603", 
"00-01-18200-00865", "00-01-71990-00027", "00-01-85498-73837", 
"00-02-71250-00019", "00-01-80660-95615", "00-02-70310-30701", 
"00-01-85498-12345", "00-01-18200-86031", "00-01-87692-33103", 
"00-01-62067-05155", "00-01-18200-53218", "00-01-87000-50901", 
"00-01-71990-48016", "00-01-73360-11214", "00-01-34100-00579", 
"00-01-34100-62340", "00-01-87692-10012", "00-01-34100-62340", 
"00-01-70310-00012", "00-01-18200-00016", "00-01-80157-61147", 
"00-01-18200-04997", "00-01-18200-00784", "00-01-71439-45712", 
"00-01-18200-00833", "00-01-71990-77603", "00-01-34100-15340", 
"00-01-71990-30030", "00-01-18200-61047", "00-01-34100-30306", 
"00-01-34100-15505", "00-03-18200-00697", "00-04-25569-19231", 
"00-01-18200-04997", "00-01-34100-15602", "00-01-71990-47712", 
"00-01-22100-01640", "00-01-34100-15256", "06-01-85165-10502", 
"00-01-71990-30005", "00-02-18200-29031", "00-02-71250-00019", 
"06-01-35985-10062", "06-01-19699-00002", "00-01-18200-00468", 
"00-01-34100-17505", "00-02-71990-77005", "00-01-34100-80706", 
"00-02-18200-00801", "00-01-34100-48602", "00-01-34100-00904", 
"00-01-73360-50202", "00-01-34100-30306", "00-01-89961-00120", 
"00-01-34100-10602", "00-01-34100-03306", "00-02-72890-00012", 
"00-01-62067-05142", "00-01-18200-53168", "00-01-34100-77435", 
"00-01-34100-48574", "00-01-72890-00011", "00-01-83820-07531", 
"00-01-34100-01222", "07-01-18200-53025", "00-01-62067-04955", 
"00-01-18200-79047", "00-03-41827-00046", "00-01-18200-15047", 
"06-01-85165-10106", "00-02-18200-87418", "00-02-18200-29031", 
"00-01-18200-00773", "00-01-82488-13000", "00-01-73360-13343", 
"00-01-62067-38055", "00-01-34100-50222", "00-01-71990-00008", 
"00-01-85498-73837", "00-01-34100-00009", "00-01-71990-90029", 
"00-01-34100-00009", "00-01-34100-01509")
```

EDIT 3:

Using the data in EDIT 2: I have the following examples.

`00-01-34100-01509` which is one of the `IDs` in the second edit data. This should collapse to `1341001509`.

Example 2:

`00-01-62067-05155` should collapse to `16206705155`

Example 3: `00-01-82488-12356` should collapse to `18248812356`

Example 4: `06-01-19699-00002` should collapse to `611969900002`

Example 5: `00-01-09439-00008` should collapse to `10943900008`

Example 6: `00-01-09439-00008` should collapse to `10943900008`

The common theme here is that it is just the first leading zeros being removed. That is the leading zeros in `S` and `G`.

So what I am now trying to do is to `gsub` the `IDs` data removing the `-` so I will have data which looks like the following (taking example 6) - 00010943900008 then from here remove the leading zeros so the data becomes 10943900008. Which is much simpler than what I had previously thought.

EDIT 4:

When I run my version

I get the following consol output:

```
> df_panel$COLUPC <- gsub("-","",df_panel$UPC)
> df_panel$COLUPC <- sub("^[0]+", "", df_panel$COLUPC) 
> beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch <- beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPC %in% df_panel$COLUPC
> sum(beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch == FALSE) 
[1] 896
> sum(beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch == TRUE) 
[1] 19119
> 
> beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPC <- as.character(beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPC)
> df <- full_join(df_panel, beer_PANEL_GR, by = "COLUPC") #Joining with UPC causes us to lose a lot of observations
> dim(df)
[1] 5293488      40
```

When I run your version I get the following consol output:

```
> # remove 0s at the beginning of the string, or preceded by "-"
> df_panel$COLUPC <- gsub("(?<=^|-)0","", df_panel$UPC, perl = TRUE)
>   
>   # remove dashes
> df_panel$COLUPC <- gsub("-", "", df_panel$COLUPC)
>   # remove leading zeros
> df_panel$COLUPC <- gsub("^0+", "", df_panel$COLUPC)
> 
> beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch <- beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPC %in% df_panel$COLUPC
> sum(beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch == FALSE) 
[1] 7382
> sum(beer_PANEL_GR$COLUPCmatch == TRUE) 
[1] 12633
> 
> df2 <- full_join(df_panel, beer_PANEL_GR, by = "COLUPC") 
> dim(df2)
[1] 3564132      40
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding back trailing zeros in an identification column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430257/adding-back-trailing-zeros-in-an-identification-column)

Comment: So what I have been doing is writing the digits on a piece of paper. For example `13410015602` then I would count backwards 5 digits so I = `15602` now since this did not have a `0` on the first digit then this section has 5 digits. Then I would count back another 5 digits from this point V =  `4100` I now know that this digit would have had a `leading zero` it should be `04100` but leading zeros were removed. I know this because `G` must have 1 digit and `S` must have no more than 2 digits and the remaining digits in my example are `13` so S = `1` and G = `3`.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this isn't a duplicate of your question I answered last week. I don't see any new information about the algorithm by which we can decide which numbers belong to which part of the ID

Comment: Yes it is very similar, however I am doing more with the data by splitting it up etc. and the solution last week you answered (thanks again) turned out to not work when I applied it to the data. It worked perfectly on the sample data but due to the complexity of the structre of the data I must have mis-understood something when I was writing that question. You answered that question as I asked, I was just a little wrong in the structure / understanding of the data (which is entirely my fault)

Comment: @user113156 If leading zeroes are removed on every component individually, why couldn't that be I = 05602, V = 41001, G = 0, S = 13?

Comment: I just did `unique(G)` on the whole data and this is the results  `[1]  1  3  2  4  5 NA` also `unique(S)` gave `[1]  0 27  7  6  3 NA`

Comment: @Frank Took the words out of my mouth on Example 3. user113156, the information you've provided doesn't clear up the ambiguity in where a zero needs to be added. We can follow a fixed pattern like we did in my answer to your last question, but the fact remains that the zero could go in either `I` or `V` for Example 3

Comment: I certainly see your point and I am trying different examples. I honestly do not know why this data provider thought it was a good idea to remove the leading zeros.

Comment: It depends on what you're using this data for, but what if instead of trying to reconstruct the IDs, you just strip the leading zeros off your "correct" data to match the incorrect data. You'd have to check duplicates before/after to see if the IDs are sufficiently unique that they are still unique without the leading zeros.

Comment: I was just thinking that I am making an edit to the original post. I think this is the way to go.

Comment: Okay I added more data and I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your edit, how about:

```
library(dplyr)

# remove 0s at the beginning of the string, or preceded by "-"
gsub("(?<=^|-)0","", IDs, perl = TRUE) %>% 

  # remove dashes
  gsub("-", "", .) %>% 
  # remove leading zeros
  gsub("^0+", "", .)

[1] "1418270712"  "1523001540"  "1182000987"  "1838207131"  "1341001222" 
[6] "13410050602"
```

Comment: Okay I think I got the leading zeros problem solved. I will update my original question with everything I have found. It appear much simpler than what I was originally thinking!

Comment: I have updated the original post under EDIT 3. The problem is much simpler I believe now.

Comment: Yes I had something similar `df_panel$COLUPC <- gsub("-","",df_panel$UPC)
df_panel$COLUPC <- sub("^[0]+", "", df_panel$COLUPC) `

Comment: Thanks again for your help, its much appreciated!

Comment: To replicate what happened to your data, `sub("^[0]+", "", df_panel$COLUPC)` isn't going to be sufficient because it's not going to remove leading zeros within each ID. You need the positive look-behind in my first statement to do that.

Comment: Yes I have applied both methods (yours and mine) - yours gives me 3.5 million observations, mine gives me 5.3 millions so something is not right (probably my version) I just need to study both versions more indepth

Comment: You shouldn't be getting different row counts from the operations. Substitution operations shouldn't change `nrow(df_panel)`

Comment: I have added an "EDIT 4" to my original comment so you can see the code and output I obtain